# PyMongo: ObjectId() prints string instead of Object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I am trying to convert an `id` string to an `ObjectId()`

I have the following imports:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
```

If i print:

```
print(ObjectId(session['id']))
print(ObjectId())
```

I get the following:

```
58a09f4255c205690833f9dd
58f7d1606cb710c54a14ae82
```

Expected:

```
ObjectId("58a09f4255c205690833f9dd")
ObjectId("58f7d1606cb710c54a14ae82")
```

FYI:

```
pymongo==3.4.0
bson==0.4.7
```

I have tried (with no luck):

```
import bson
print(bson.ObjectId(session['id']))
print(bson.ObjectId())
```

Comment: `print` calls `str` on each argument, so `print(ObjectId())` outputs the result of `str(ObjectId())`. You'll have to call `repr` (explicitly): `print(repr(ObjectId()))`

Comment: thanks - make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already converting converting your id `string` to `ObjectId` indeed.
As print function returns your `ObjectId` to `string` type in order to print properly, instead of printing the value itself, try printing the type.

```
var1 = ObjectId(session['id'])
var2 = ObjectId()

print(var1)
print(var2)
print(type(var1))
print(type(var2))
```

Returns:

```
58a09f4255c205690833f9dd
58f7d1606cb710c54a14ae82
<class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
<class 'bson.objectid.ObjectId'>
```

So you can use `var1` and `var2` in where you want to use your ObjectIds.

Answer (score 1):

Before of converting directly from `str` to `objectid` try you validate with `ObjectId.is_valid` if is a validate str for `objectid` return `True` so you can do something as like:

```
  if ObjectId(session['id']):
      try:
          id_object_valid = ObjectId(session['id'])
      except (InvalidId, TypeError):
          return False
```